# Copying Windows 7 system onto Mac Pro partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, partitioning

Instead of installing a new Windows 7 system onto a mac pro partition, is it possible to copy over my complete Windows 7 system directly onto the partition, and get it to run? I just bought the mac pro, and it's running OSX 10.6...

**Copied from a comment:**
I wish to make a windows partition on the mac pro startup disk, but instead of installing windows, was wondering if I can copy over from my pc laptop byte for byte my windows system into said partition, and successfully run it

Comment: This might be one of those try it and find out scenarios.  The operation is non-destructive so no biggie if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use bootcamp to create a partition
2. use a windows installation disk to format that partition to ntfs
3. cancel the installation
4. use a disk utility to copy the windows drive to the new partition
5. install bootcamp drivers.

Answer (score 0):

No. Windows won't run on HFS+, and it doesn't like the hardware changing under it that drastically.

Comment: Sounds like the OP doesn't necessarily want it on the same _partition_, just the same disk. (And even so, virtualization is always an option.)

Comment: That's right... I phrased my question poorly. I wish to make a windows partition on the mac pro startup disk, but instead of installing windows, was wondering if I can copy over from my pc laptop byte for byte my windows system into said partition, and successfully run it...

Comment: Potentially (it can be done on PCs), but it will not like the boot sector, so you may have to fight with Boot Camp.

Comment: Might loading the Apple drivers from the OSX dvd afterwards, as done with a normal windows install, solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use Acronis True Image with Universal Restore to do a bare metal recovery onto your mac, then load up the boot camp drivers.